# Visual Studio 2013 Error List not showing errors on failed builds

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

My VS2013 Professional just stopped showing build errors in my error list (which is more user friendly as i can click on errors and go straight to the offending line). Build errors e.g non-existent method on an object now only show up at build time in the Output window. This is proving to make my life harder as i now need to run the project every single time, to see errors which i should really get in the error list before runtime.

I have tried

- Deleting suo files
- Checked, Always show error list if build finished with errors option
- Started a new project

And nothing is working.

Maybe iam just confusing VS2013 with another IDE, but iam pretty sure VS2013 is suppose to show errors **in the Error List** when build fails with errors such as

> C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\MyProj\UI\Main.cs(149,213,149,221): error CS1061:
>   'Helper.Track' does not contain a definition for 'location' and no
>   extension method 'location' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Helper.Track' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

which are wrongly showing only in my output window.

Comment: Do you maybe have Errors filtered out?  (That is, only showing Warnings and/or Messages, or none at all)??

Comment: Nope..not filtered...

Comment: maybe try a clean and rebuild

Comment: I have the same problem in VS2015 v14.0.23107 , did you find any solution?

Comment: Same problem here. It happened in Communit Edition after some time, then I installed Pro over it and it had the problem immediately.

Comment: When you say "wrongly showing only in my output window", you mean the error is genuine, and so it should also show in the Error List, right?

Comment: Talking from experience: Make sure the search field is empty.

Answer (score 6):

Right hand side of ErrorList, select **Build + Intellisense**. Worked for me

Comment: Switching back to `Build Only` may then just keep the errors displayed.

Answer (score 3):

I'm seeing this in 2015 every once and a while.  For me changing the "Show issues generated" drop down gets them to show up.  Even if I was already on "Build + IntelliSense", dropping it down to "Build Only" or "IntelliSense Only" can get them to display (without having to rebuild).  Sometimes I can take it back to B+I and keep the revealed errors, sometimes not.  Rather weird.

Comment: On VS2015, for me too: *switching* between `B+Intelli` and `Build Only` made errors appear with `B. Only` that previously didn't show up when `B. Only` was selected.

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem for ages, just worked it out.

Your problem is over 6 months old, so I assume you've worked it out, but for others, make sure the dropdown list in the top left corner of the error window (next to the error count, under the text 'Error List') is set to 'Entire Solution'.

Mine was set to 'Current Document'.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with VS2015 Update 3 RC and Xamarin (.Forms shared project).
Compiler don't stop, errors were only showed in the output window.
This only for Xamarin projects (with VB.NET projects all has worked as expected)...
To try find the reason for the problem, I have changed the Build Output in VS:

- menu "Tools - Options"
- from the left panel: "Projects And Solutions: Build And Run":
- change "MSBuild Output Verbosity" from "Minimal" to "Diagnostic"

**After doing that, the compiler has stopped and the error was showed..**
After that, I have set the option **back from "Diagnostic" to "Minimal"** (like it was before) and... it has worked also with "Minimal" (to be sure, I also have restarted VS)...

**So.. it seems that only to change (touch) the setting (MSBuild Output Verbosity") has solved the problem and that this is a bug in VS and/or the Xamarin integration Software...**

Answer (score 1):

Restarting Visual Studio did the trick for me.  Seems to also have worked for one of the contributors to [this Microsoft Social post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/49a72b3b-6b83-40a8-b8a1-8e1a82db5e3d/visual-studio-shows-build-failed-but-no-errors-are-displayed?forum=visualstudiogeneral).  I had tried all the answers on this page to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the view menu and select Errors List.  That's what you're looking for.

Comment: The window is there....but showing warning only.........and error filter not working

Comment: check the filter (the funnel thingy at the top left corner of error list) and see if you've got current project selected.

Comment: I have no "funnel thingy" (in VS 2010). I'd like to show Errors, then Warnings, then Messages, not them all scattered about willy-nilly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have `Build + Intellisense` selected within the `Error List` pane. By default on VS2015 it is set to `Build Only`

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem with xamarin project in vs 2015. Opened a non Xamarin and the error list worked fine. Then reopened the xamarin project and now the error list was started to work in it also. So the solution for me was to open non xamarin related project.

Answer (score 0):

If I select the Solution in the Solution Window, right click Solution and select either Build Solution or Rebuild Solution, the errors and warnings show up in the error list.