# Xamarin.forms with Visual Studio stopped showing error messages

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I'm working on my first Xamarin.forms project and Visual Studio seems to be doing everything possible to slow down my progress on this. From the start I've not had any intellisense support for the xamarin.forms or my own objects, but after trying many suggested fixes I've just about learnt to live with this.

However, now Visual Studio has stopped even giving me error messages, something which up until now it was doing. On my computer I've got installs of both VS2015 & VS2017. Some time last week 2017 stopped doing it, so after a bit of failing to find a solution, I went to 2015 and carried on as normal. This morning I've come in to find that 2015 now isn't giving errors either.

If my project is free from compile errors then my project will build and run on my android device as expected, however, if there are any compile errors, then I get the error list tab popping up showing 0 errors and 3 warnings (the warnings always being the same: 1 about version conflicts in dependent assemblies and 2 that file names exceed the 260 character limit within the UWP and iOS versions of the project).

Has anyone else experienced anything like this before? As you can imagine, the combination of limited intellisense and no compile error debugging makes for a pretty horrific dev experience and is seriously undermining the supposed dev time benefits of using Xamarin in the first place.

James

Comment: In case anyone else is having this problem, here's someone else that had the same issue, unfortunately, the solution they used isn't working for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40886160/5419504

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after getting pretty desperate for a solution, I tried deleting the .shproj file within my shared project which resulted in visual studio displaying the compile error messages despite it not actually being able to load the project correctly any more. After restoring the .shproj file back, I am now getting error messages and able to build my project.

I don't feel particularly confident that this will be a long term solution to my problem, but for now I am at least able to get on with my work.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, it would help other community members who meet the same issue, you could mark it as the answer:)

Comment: I'm reluctant to mark this as the answer, since this doesn't seem to work in 2017 and needs to be done every time I load up 2015. I'm now considering uninstalling both '15 & '17, and reinstalling just '17